# How to get correct class, predicted class and prediction probability in Random Forest in R?

Tags: r, classification, probability, random-forest

I am using randomForest for classification of data and I am unable to understand:

1- How can we obtain the information (preferably in a dataframe of 3 columns) which tells us the real classification in `testData` (e.g. in below example `Species` column), prediction made by random forest, and the probability score of that prediction. For example just consider the below data set and 1 case where in `testData` the Species (blinded information for random forest) was **versicolor** but it was predicted wrongly by classifier as **virginica** with a probability score of **0.67**. I want this kind of information but don't know how can I obtain this

2- How can we get the confusion matrix for `testData` and `trainingData` which also gives us the class.error, like in the case when we print the model.

```
data(iris)
set.seed(111)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2))
trainData <- iris[ind==1,]    
testData <- iris[ind==2,]
#grow forest
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=trainData)
print(iris.rf)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = trainData) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 3.33%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         45          0         0  0.00000000
versicolor      0         39         1  0.02500000
virginica       0          3        32  0.08571429

**#predict using the training again...**
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, trainData)
table(observed = trainData$Species, predicted = iris.pred)

           predicted
observed     setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         45          0         0
  versicolor      0         40         0
  virginica       0          0        35

**#Testing on testData**
irisPred<-predict(iris.rf, newdata = testData)
table(irisPred, testData$Species)

irisPred     setosa versicolor virginica
setosa          5          0         0
versicolor      0          8         1
virginica       0          2        14
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the caret package to run random forest with trainControl:

```
library(caret)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

model <- train(Species ~ .,trainData,
           method='rf',TuneLength=3,
           trControl=trainControl(
             method='cv',number=10,
             classProbs = TRUE))
model$results

irisPred_species<-predict(iris.rf, newdata = testData)
irisPred_prob<-predict(iris.rf, newdata = testData, "prob")

out.table <- data.frame(actual.species = testData$Species, pred.species = irisPred_species, irisPred_prob)
```

You can get the error rate by:

```
iris.rf$err.rate
```

And the confusion matrix:

```
iris.rf$confusion
```

Comment: Where are you initializing/assigning a value to the `iris.rf` object?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified: I followed your code above (iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=trainData)).